# $\begin{array}{ll}\max\limits_{{H: H\geq 0}} s'Hs.\end{array}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

Given real vector $s=[\sqrt s_1 \quad \sqrt s_2]'$, such that $s_1 \geq s_2$.

Variable is $H\in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$. $H$ is positive semi-definite. I want to know what structure of $H$ will maximize $s'Hs$:

\begin{array}{ll}\max\limits_{{H: H\geq 0}} s'Hs.\end{array}

My attempt: Since I am interested on the structure of $H$, first I normalize it. Let this be normalization of $H$: \begin{equation}
\hat{H}=
\begin{bmatrix}
 h_1 & h_2    \\
 h_2 & h_3  
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}

Then rewrite the condition:

\begin{array}{ll}\max\limits_{{\hat{H}: h_1+h_3=1, \\h_2^2\leq h_1h_3}} s'\hat{H}s=\max\limits_{{H: h_1+h_3=1, \\h_2^2\leq h_1h_3}} h_1s_1+2h_2\sqrt{s_1s_2}+h_3s_2=\max\limits_{{h_1: 1>h_1>0}} (\sqrt{h_1s_1}+\sqrt{(1-h_1)s_2})^2.\end{array}

Now I can say only that $h_2=\sqrt{h_1h_3}$ gives maximum, i.e. $\hat{H}$ is rank 1. Can we say more about the structure of $\hat{H}$?

Comment: As long as you maximize also over $s_1$ and $s_2$, your maximum is $\infty$.

Comment: @amsmath, $s_1$ and $s_2$ are constant, we just know that $s_1\geq s_2$. I expect that the knowledge of the fact that $s1\geq s_2$ will help to choose best $h_1$.

Comment: Then delete it below the max because this means that you also maximize over those two. What you have is just $\max_{H\ge 0}$.

Comment: @amsmath ok, done

Comment: You still have it in the title. ;-) The max of your function is attained at $h_1 = \tfrac{s_1}{s_1+s_2}$.

Comment: @amsmath can you please explain a little bit? I did some simple examples when $s_1=s_2$ and got result $h_1=1/2$. but have difficulty for general case

Comment: Put $t = \sqrt{h_1}$ and $\sigma_j = \sqrt{s_j}$. Then you have to maximize $f(t) = \sigma_1 t + \sigma_2\sqrt{1-t^2}$ over $[0,1]$. It starts at $\sigma_2$ and ends at $\sigma_1$ (the larger one). In between it has a max at $t = c/\sqrt{1+c^2}$, where $c = \sigma_1/\sigma_2\ge 1$. If $\sigma_2 = 0$, treat it as $t=1$ and $c=\infty$. Hence, the max of the expression is at $h_1 = t^2 = c^2/(1+c^2) = s_1/(s_1+s_2)$.

Comment: @amsmath thank you a lot

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I thought that would be one way to normalize the matrix

Comment: @Lee The feasible region is a spectrahedron called spectraplex (rhymes with simplex).

Comment: The maximum does not exist unless $s=0$. Pick any $H>0$. Then $s'(cH)s\to+\infty$ as $c\to+\infty$. You need to add some constraint about the norm of $H$.

Comment: @user1551 the normalization that I did, is kind of norm constrain as well. The gain $c$ cannot exist in my situation